# how can I catch event when navigate the url

Tags: c#

this is the console that call browser and navigate url, how can I check the 
   event when navigated url to check conflict event.

```
 private static void ThreadStart()
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.Name = "webBrowser";
        browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        browser.TabIndex = 0;
        browser.Url = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com");

        Form form = new Form();
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        form.Controls.Add(browser);
        form.Name = "Browser";

        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

Comment: _"the event when navigated url to check conflict event"_ does this make any sense?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DocumentCompleted` event on WebBrowser  :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx